# Resizing without changing the controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I am sure many developers are frustrated by the flickering when resize events happens faster than onPaint event.

I have created many user objects that is shown on the main form.
When I try to set the location and size of each controls at the resize event of the main form, I get the flickering.

To resolve this I wanted to do a new approach as mentioned below.

1. When resizeBegin event is triggered, show a borderline of current frame
2. When resize event is triggered, only the borderline will be resized leaving the controls in the main frame untouched.

   - The tricky part is when the borderline is larger than original size, I want it to show the background of the window as it self.
     [Click for Enlarge image](http://jokerham.hosting.paran.com/DataUpload/enlarge.png)
   - On the contrary if the borderline is smaller then, I still want the original objects to be shown
     [Click for Reduce image](http://jokerham.hosting.paran.com/DataUpload/reduce.png)
3. When resizeEnd then the borderline will be hidden and the controls in the frame will be resized.

Does anybody know how to implement the tricky part mentioned at resize?

Comment: Which UI technology are you talking about?

Comment: JABFreeware, thank you for the comment. Added the question at the end.

Comment: Eric J. What do you mean by which UI? I am just using System.Windows.Forms UIs and System.Drawing UIs. Does that answer your questions?

Comment: Do want to just hide all the controls?

Comment: @JABFreeware, No. I want the controls to be as it is and visible. (Not hidden due to the reduced frame).

Comment: In the old days of unmanaged code with VB6 & etc you needed to handle resizing controls. These days with .Net everyone uses Anchoring and Docking - suggest you test this out as it should overcome the flickering?

Comment: Not an answer to your exact question but you can stop flickering quite easily, see one of my old answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13999980/1909055

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson, Thank you for the comment. Unfortunetly, there are some controls that overlaps. This makes it difficult to use anchoring and docking.

Comment: @MitchTWC, This was close to what I was looking for, but unfortunetly, it does not takes care of the paint events of controls in the form. Thank you anyway.